# Nativescript: unable to create application... Failed to load module: ...app/main.js

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, angular, nativescript

I'm fiddling with the sample-Groceries application, and I've installed NativeScript and angular 2 on two machines now and on both, I get the same error message when I try to do:

```
tns run android --emulator
```

IOS runs without problems but on Android, I get the following error:

`unhandled exception java.lang.runtimeexception unable to create application... Failed to load module: ...app/main.js`

(see image) I also tried an older API version 22.

The only answers I found were about changing the app.js, but I can't find that file.

Hope someone can help.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a pretty simple issue to fix;
Enter your the app folder and type:

**npm install tns-core-modules@latest --save**

And then you need to rebuild you app and you should be good to go.

See: http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=323

Comment: If i build the project using root account, there were not errors, but i got this error for normal users. Anyway thx